# argument provided to a shell function interrupt another shell script running through it

Tags: bash, shell, weblogic

I'm trying to execute startWebLogic.sh through a shell function, but when I pass a argument to particular function, the argument is being taken into the startWebLogic.sh(this is a standard script provided with weblogic installation and it is designed to accepts different arguments) script and block the execution. Is there anyway that I can stop passing the argument to the second script?

```
functionWeblogicfunction()
{
signal=$1

if [ "$signal" == "start" ]
then

./startWebLogic.sh

fi
}

functionWeblogicfunction "start"
```

Comment: The argument `start` will not be passed to `./startWebLogic.sh` as the script is currently written. You can use `set -x` to confirm this.

Comment: You can use `shift 1` to remove the first argument from $@ and then call `./startweblogic.sh $@`